What is the correct pattern to use trpc query calls in the nextjs application?
I'm learning nextjs coming from pure frontend react.
And trying to understand how to implement using trpc calls to the backend.
This is something I'm used to doing, but it is not the correct way in this instance.
const [weight, setWeight] = useState<ChildWeightDataType[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (activeChildId) {
    const clientQuery =  trpc.children.getWeight.useQuery({
      childId: activeChildId
    });
    setWeight(clientQuery.data)
  }
}, [activeChildId]);

I guess the issue here is that useQuery is a hook, so I'm not allowed to use it inside another hook. What is the correct pattern here?

You just use the useQuery and deconstruct it in order to get the data property.
const {data} = trpc..useQuery()

You can then useEffect to listen to changes in data and do the effect you want

The problem is that I don't have the data jet for useQuery. I think I might have found the solution with "enabled" parameter for the query.

You listen for changes of "data" but have a conditional inside the useEffect that only applies if there is data.
You won't have the data instantly, unless you prefetch.
You can also use other properties like "isLoading" in order to show spinners and such while TRPC is fetching

You are correct in that you cannot call React hooks from the useEffect hook's callback function.
It seems trpc.useQuery is a thin wrapper around Tanstack's useQuery,  so you can hoist the trpc.children.getWeight.useQuery({childId:activeChildId}); to the top-level and pass the appropriate query options to invoke the query when the childId is available. See Dependent Queries for details.
Example:
const { data: weight } = trpc.children.getWeight.useQuery(
  // query input
  { childId: activeChildId },
  // options
  {
    enabled: !!activeChildId
  },
);

Copying data or storing derived data is usually a React anti-pattern, i.e. storing data into the local weight state instead of just referencing data directly, but if you wanted to keep a local copy of the fetched data so it can be updated independently from the queried data you can use useEffect to synchronize the state.
const [weight, setWeight] = useState<ChildWeightDataType[]>([]);

const { data } = trpc.children.getWeight.useQuery(
  // input
  { childId: activeChildId },
  // options
  {
    enabled: !!activeChildId
  },
);

useEffect(() => {
  if (data) {
    setWeight(data);
  }
}, [data]);

